# Non Locking transaction in NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, transactions

I need to execute a long runnign process in a production environment (please dont ask why), I'm opening a transaction in this process using ReadUncommited, but it is locking all the tables involved, I do run some updates on the tables. So when I run this process and then I try to run a query on any of these tables, the query times out because of the lock.

Is there anyway that my transaction will not lock the tables? If I dont use a transaction the tables are not locked.

Here is my code

```
ISession session = sessionProvider.GetCurrentSession();
session.SetBatchSize(100);
session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);

var solrCandidateFactory = _container.GetInstance<ISolrCandidateFactory>();
int id;

while (concurrentQueue.TryDequeue(out id))
{
    var cv = session.Get<Curriculum>(id,LockMode.None);
    SolrCandidate fromCandidate = solrCandidateFactory.CreateFromCandidate(cv);

    _candidateIndexer.Index(fromCandidate);

    session
        .CreateSQLQuery("update Curriculum set IndexedAt = :time where Id = :id")
        .SetParameter("time", DateTime.Now)
        .SetParameter("id", id)

        .ExecuteUpdate();
}

session.Transaction.Commit();
```

Comment: Writes must always lock so that you can rollback.

Comment: Do you really need to have atomicity on the whole batch ? Can't you just move the BeginTransaction and Commit inside of the while loop ?

Comment: is there an overhead on doing that? I thought there was that's why I wanted to commit in batches.

Answer (score 0):

The lock may be a result of Sql Server lock escalation. I'd suggest you to break the transaction into smaller batches, indexing only 50-100 entities in one transaction, commit it, index next batch in another transaction.

By the way, ISession is not intended for batch processing and will consume a lot more memory compare to IStatelessSession.

And I think it's not a good idea to use ReadUncommitted in this kind of transaction. ReadUncommitted might be OK for a non-critical read-only transaction like listing for displaying purpose. There is no such thing as nonlocking transaction.